# Problem in flex-layout comes when ran ng serve

Tags: angular, typescript, flexbox

sorry I tried what this [link](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/702) say me to do but nothing got changed someone could help me pls.
Console of error

---

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(25,15): error TS2416: Property '*registry' in type 'MockMatchMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatchMedia'.
      Type 'Map' is not assignable to type 'Map'.
        Type 'MockMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type 'MediaQueryList'.
          Types of property 'removeListener' are incompatible.
            Type '(*: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject) => void' is not assignable to type '(listener: MediaQueryListListener) => void'.
              Types of parameters '_' and 'listener' are incompatible.
                Type 'MediaQueryListListener' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
                  Type 'MediaQueryListListener' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerObject'.
                    Property 'handleEvent' is missing in type 'MediaQueryListListener'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(82,5): error TS2416: Property 'removeListener' in type 'MockMediaQueryList' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MediaQueryList'.
      Type '(*: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject) => void' is not assignable to type '(listener: MediaQueryListListener) => void'.
        Types of parameters '*' and 'listener' are incompatible.
          Type 'MediaQueryListListener' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
            Type 'MediaQueryListListener' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerObject'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(83,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListEventMap'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(83,99): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListEventMap'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(84,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListEventMap'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(84,102): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListEventMap'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(95,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListEvent'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(30,5): error TS2416: Property 'removeListener' in type 'ServerMediaQueryList'
    is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MediaQueryList'.
      Type '(*: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject) => void' is not assignable to type '(listener: MediaQueryListListener) => void'.
        Types of parameters '*' and 'listener' are incompatible.
          Type 'MediaQueryListListener' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
            Type 'MediaQueryListListener' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerObject'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(31,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListEventMap'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(31,99): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListEventMap'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(32,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListEventMap'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(32,102): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListEventMap'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(46,15): error TS2416: Property '*registry' in type 'ServerMatchMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatchMedia'.
      Type 'Map' is not assignable to type 'Map'.
        Type 'ServerMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type 'MediaQueryList'.
          Types of property 'removeListener' are incompatible.
            Type '(*: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject) => void' is not assignable to type '(listener: MediaQueryListListener) => void'.
              Types of parameters '_' and 'listener' are incompatible.
                Type 'MediaQueryListListener' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
                  Type 'MediaQueryListListener' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerObject'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(58,15): error TS2416: Property '_buildMQL' in type 'ServerMatchMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatchMedia'.
      Type '(query: string) => ServerMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type '(query: string) => MediaQueryList'.
        Type 'ServerMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type 'MediaQueryList'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(60,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListEvent'.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a solution if someone having the same problems IDK if its the best to resolve but  for me this works:

```
    npm install @angular/flex-layout@6.0.0-beta.18
```

Comment: Getting error `ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(72,67): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected. node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,33): error TS1005: ';' expected. node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,39): error TS1109: Expression expected. node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(79,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected`

Comment: This worked for me as well. https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/851#issuecomment-428679938

Answer (score 8):

Inside your project:
Remove/delete flex layout from your package.json
then run:

```
npm update
```

followed by:

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout@latest --save
```

This is will automatically install the latest version of flex thats compatible with your angular material.

Answer (score 4):

One time I had some similar issue with flex-layout and `MatchMedia`. Later after much debugging the culprit was rxjs.

So can you please check if you are not using semantic versioning for these package in your package.json file.

with the below, I was getting the error

```
"rxjs": "^6.2.2",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
```

**Changing** to this solves the issue

```
"rxjs": "6.2.2",
"rxjs-compat": "6.2.1",
```

Please give this a try and check

Comment: @filip  I would like to know if this solves your question. Because I always advocate not to use semantic versioning in production code, breaks sometimes even without changing the code, build break happens.

Comment: I already did this, in the link they say to do that but in my case, my answer was what I needed to make my project works again @Vivek Kumar but if someone has this kind of problems your answer could help someone. TY anyway

Comment: that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I uninstalled @angular/flex-layout
It solved immediately the problem.

This happened after updating to angular 7 from v 6.2

Hope this will help.

Comment: How does uninstalling something you need solve a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Solved this issue for me by removing **@angular/flex-layout** from package.json

Try running

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout@7.0.0-beta.24
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I am guessing that the new version of Flex Layout `^7.0.0-beta.19` is not completely compatible with the older version of angular i.e below 7. I ran `ng-update --all` and updated my `typescript` version to `3.1.3` and everything was running fine. You can get more information from  [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/851#issuecomment-428679938)

Comment: Its the same answer I made if you wish you could edit my answer putting this information, anyway ty

Answer (score 1):

its have some version related problem ,just run the command ng update all

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(72,67): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected. node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected. node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,33): error TS1005: ';' expected. node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,39): error TS1109: Expression expected. node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(79,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected

I resolved it by installing typescript version 2.9.1

Comment: nice sharing your answer if someone had the same problem you could help someone

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked fine :

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout@6.0.0-beta.18 --save
```

Answer (score 1):

changing "rxjs": "~6.4.0" to "rxjs": "6.4.0" works for me 
I also updated the flex layout to latest version
followed @RileyManda and @Vivek kumar worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I corrected the problem file, the node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(82,5):

error TS2416: Property 'removeListener' in type 'MockMediaQueryList' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MediaQueryList'. Type '(: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject) => void' is not assignable to type '(listener: MediaQueryListListener) => void'. Types of parameters 'low _ dash' and 'listener' are incompatible.  The type of "listener" a parameter is not the same type as the "low _ dash" parameter. I replaced the "_" parameter with the keyword "this" and the script is now working and ng serve and ng build are compiling 100%.